# Não consigo pegar conteúdo (número) de algumas tags li

Tags: javascript, html, dom, objetos

A ideia é pegar uma sequência de valores dispostos em li's que compartilham a mesma classe, converter para inteiro, somar para então realizar um teste condicional.

Eu estou usando `document.getElementsByClassName(nomedaclasse)` (já falaram que há instrução mais nova para usar). Pelo visto não é um vetor que é retornado, pois aparece HTMLCollection, já tentei `document.getElementsByClassName(nomedaclasse).value`, porém retorna undefined.

Segue abaixo o que eu tenho tentado:

```css
@font-face{
  font-family: 'FonteSite';
  src: url("../_fonts/product-sans/product-sans-regular.ttf ");
}

body {
  font-family: FonteSite, sans-serif;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  
}

.header {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 20px;
  width: 40%;
  height: 180px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  position: relative;
}

/*inputs*/
.text {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.situacao {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100px;
  height: 20px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  border: 1px solid tomato;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.km_trocadeoleo {
  right: 5px;
  top: 10px;
}

.km_alinhamento {
  right: 5px;
  top: 40px;
}

.result_revisao {
  right: 5px;
  top: 70px;
}

.container {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
  height: 600px;
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.data {
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.servico {
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-width: 200px;
} 

.km_final {
  width: 40%;
  height: 60%;
  padding-left: 5px;
  background-color: #ccc;
  max-width: 150px;
}

li {
  list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="_css/style.css">
  <title>Controle de revisão de veículo</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="header">
    <label for="km_tdo">KM troca de óleo:</label><input class="text" type="text" name="km_tdo" id="km_tdo" autofocus data-rule-required="true"/><button type="button" onclick="estadoAtual()">Ok</button><div class="situacao km_trocadeoleo" id="km_trocadeoleo"></div><br>
    <label for="km_alin">KM alinhamento:</label><input class="text" type="text" name="km_alin" id="km_alin" data-rule-required="true"/><button type="button">Ok</button><div class="situacao km_alinhamento"></div><br>
    <label for="revisao">Revisão:</label><input class="text" type="text" name="revisao" id="revisao" data-rule-required="true"/><button type="button">Ok</button><div class="situacao result_revisao"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="data">
      <span style="font-weight: 500; padding-left: 25px">Data</span><br>
      01/01/2019 
      01/01/2019 
      01/15/2019 
      01/23/2019 
      01/30/2019 
      02/27/2019
      03/12/2019
      03/28/2019
      04/15/2019
      04/29/2019
      05/21/2019
    </div>
    <div class="servico">
      <span style="font-weight: 500; margin-left: 50px">Serviço</span><br>
      TROCA DE OLEO 
      ALINHAMENTO<br> 
      REVISÃO<br> 
      REVISÃO<br> 
      TROCA DE OLEO <br>
      TROCA DE OLEO <br>
      TROCA DE OLEO <br>
      ALINHAMENTO <br>
      ALINHAMENTO <br>
      REVISÃO <br>
      TROCA DE OLEO 
      ALINHAMENTO 
    </div>
    <div class="km_final">
      <span style="font-weight: 500; margin-left: 25px;">KM Final</span><br>
      <ul id="teste">
        <li class="km_tdo_realizada">10</li>
        <li>7</li>
        <li>20</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li class="km_tdo_realizada">20</li>
        <li class="km_tdo_realizada">20</li>
        <li class="km_tdo_realizada">10</li>
        <li>15</li>
        <li>11</li>
        <li>20</li>
        <li class="km_tdo_realizada">30</li>
        <li>10</li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <script>
    function estadoAtual(){
      
      var valorEntradaKM = document.getElementById("km_tdo").value;
      var km_acumulada_tdo = document.getElementsByClassName('km_tdo_realizada');
      
      
/*
      if(valorEntradaKM >= 0 && valorEntradaKM <= 5){
        document.getElementById("km_trocadeoleo").style.backgroundColor="green";
    
      }*/
    }
    
  </script>
</body>
</html>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`getElementsByClassName` é a forma correta de recuperar os elementos do DOM, não existe forma mais moderna, existem formas alternativas, geralmente oferecidas por uma biblioteca externa.

Como `li` não é um elemento que possui valor, você precisa recuperar o texto por meio da propriedade `innerText` ou `innerHTML`, depois transformar esses valores em números, e depois soma-los.

Exemplo:

```
//recupero os elementos e transformo num array
var km_acumulada_elem = Array.from(document.getElementsByClassName('km_tdo_realizada'));
//recupero o texto dos elementos e converto para numérico
var km_acumulada_num = km_acumulada_elem.map(e => parseFloat(e.innerText));
//somo os resultados
var km_acumulada_tdo = km_acumulada_num.reduce((acc, i) => acc + i);
```

Ou em apenas um passo:

```
var km_acumulada_tdo = [].reduce.call(document.getElementsByClassName('km_tdo_realizada'), (acc, e) => acc + parseFloat(e.innerText), 0)
```

Answer (score 2):

Existe o `querySelectorAll`. A vantagem deste para o `getElementsByClassName` é que ele aceita seletores CSS, tornando mais flexível a seleção de elementos.

Como o `getElementsByClassName` retorna uma coleção de elementos, você precisa especificar um índice (como numa array) para poder selecionar o elemento dentro da coleção.

Ao fazer `document.getElementsByClassName(nomedaclasse).value` retorna `undefined` porque você não especificou qual elemento dentro da coleção deseja pegar o `value`, e isso se faz através de um índice. Por exemplo, para pegar o `value` do primeiro elemento da coleção, use o índice `[0]`:

```
document.getElementsByClassName(nomedaclasse)[0].value
```

Se você quiser alterar todos os elementos da coleção retornada pelo `getElementsByClassName`, você precisa percorrer um por um desses elementos usando um laço, que pode ser um `for` simples:

```
const elementos = document.getElementsByClassName("km_tdo_realizada");
for(let x = 0; x < elementos.length; x++){
   elementos[x].style.backgroundColor = "green";
}
```